# CSS: The deeper the level, the darker the color

Tags: css, nested

I have a css class like this:

```
.class {
  border: 1px solid some-color;
}
```

Elements with the same class are nested within that class; the same style rule should apply, but with a slightly darker border color the deeper the level is.

How can I achieve that?

EDIT: Regardless of how deep the level is. Maybe there is a way in javascript?

Comment: Define it explicitly. There is no automatic way.

Comment: I won't know how many nested elements there are...

Comment: CSS won't know, too.

Comment: you can do that the other way around  (the deeper the lighter) with `opacity` - http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4p4rgzs9/2/ - but it will effect the content as well.

Comment: @Danield So far I prefer your approach since it is "level count agnostic"...

Comment: I can't follow: at some depth, the border would the black color (on some particular hardware display) - because hardware has a large but finite number of colors, and there is no darker than black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate darker borders by applying a `rgba` value to the `background` property.

This way the background will get darker and darker as we deepen the div level because each child div in placed above its parent's background.

[image]

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4p4rgzs9/5/)**

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(50, 120, 10, .2)
}
div div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this is still unclear, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4p4rgzs9/6/) should illustrate what is going on

Comment: This is perfect, just what I needed!

Comment: This solutions work for empty box, and similar colors box when different color needed inside one div element then it's not work good. like 3rd div make yellow color and content blue.

Answer (score 2):

Using pure css:

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uhptcg7k/)***

MARKUP:

```
<div class=class>
    <div class=class>
        <div class=class>
            <div class=class></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

STYLE:

```
.class {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
.class *{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.class .class{
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
.class .class .class{
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.class .class .class .class{
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, Compatibility is perfect unless your boss is obsessed with running IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors

Answer (score 0):

Using SASS, if you are happy with limiting the number of levels, you could try

```
.class {
    border-color: blue;
    .class {
        border-color: darken(blue, 10%);
        .class { 
            border-color: darken(blue, 20%);
        }
    }
}
```

There are probably fancier ways of doing this is SASS or other pre-preprocessors that I am not aware of, including possibly the ability to do it to infinite levels.

Comment: We could use recursive mixins (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501895/2603230) to make it even simpler. Though I'm also curious if there's a way to support infinite levels.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way in CSS, you should **guess** how many nested elements would you have,
use a color palette based on your count, and define your classes explicitly:

[image: color palette]

```
.class { color: #D4E9FF; }
.class .class { color: #BEDFFF; }
.class .class .class { color: #A8D4FF; }
.class .class .class .class { color: #93C9FF; }
.class .class .class .class .class { color: #7DBEFF; }
```

[Sample jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vj37gby/).

Answer (score 0):

With SCSS, you can also use recursive mixins to simplify the code: (here we also make the border thicker as the level gets deeper)

```
.class {
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

@mixin border-level($target, $level: 0) {
  .class {
    border-color: darken(#ffffff, $level * 10);
    border-width: #{$level * 0.7}px;
    @if $level < $target {
      @include border-level($target, $level + 1);
    }
  }
}
@include border-level(10);
```

Simply change `@include border-level(...);` to change the number of nested levels supported.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hesyifei/efg1ksvy/